# how to get all log groups names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a lambda that exports all of our loggroups to s3, and am currently using `cloudwatchlogs.describeLogGroups` to list
all of our logGroups.

```
const logGroupsResponse = await cloudwatchlogs.describeLogGroups({ limit: 50 })
```

The issue is that we have 69 logGroups is there any way to list (ids, and names) of absolutely all logGroups in an aws account. I see it's possible to have 1000 log groups. This is a screenshot of our console:
[image]

How come `cloudwatchlogs.describeLogGroups` just allows a limit of 50 which is very small?

Comment: If you change `{ limit: 50 }` to a larger number, does it work? Which AWS SDK programming language are you using?

Comment: if I put anything above 50 it throws error: `1 validation error detected: Value '100' at 'limit' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 50`

Comment: No need for the Limit parameter (it defaults to 50 max). Just do pagination correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are using AWS JS SDK v2, [`describeLogGroups`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#describeLogGroups-property) API provides a `nextToken` in its response and also accepts a `nexToken`. This token is used for retrieving multiple log groups (more than 50) by sending multiple requests. We can use the following pattern to accomplish this:

```
const cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({region: 'us-east-1'});
let nextToken = null;
do {
    const logGroupsResponse = await cloudwatchlogs.describeLogGroups({limit: 50, nextToken: nextToken}).promise();
    
    // Do something with the retrieved log groups
    console.log(logGroupsResponse.logGroups.map(group => group.arn));

    // Get the next token. If there are no more log groups, the token will be undefined
    nextToken = logGroupsResponse.nextToken;
} while (nextToken);
```

We are querying the AWS API in loop until there are no more log groups left.